# import disconnected sql database into new sql database

Tags: sql-server, database

I had a virus on my machine, and I had to have it rebuilt, I saved the SQL Server mdf file before have the computer rebuilt. not that it was rebuilt I tried to import the database using

```
CREATE DATABASE [Invoice] 
ON PRIMARY (FILENAME = N' WHATEVER PATH THE FILE IS ')
FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG 
GO
```

That didn't I did some research I tried to use

```
sp_attach_single_file_db @dbname=Invoices, @physname 'path of Database'
```

That however didn't work either.

So after researching the error I found out that because the database wasn't closed out and I found out that I cannot import that I want to try to import the data into a new database that I've created.

I do not have any tables in the new database but I would like to import all the tables and data from `[dbo].[Invoices]` in new database. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion which has worked for me in the past, but I cant guarantee it will work for you.

Create a new blank database. Take the new database offline or stop sql server. Replace the new database MDF file with the old database MDF file. Remove any log file from the newly created database. Try to start sql server. See if the database can be accessed.

Again, I can't guarantee this will work, but definitely worth a try if you are in a bind.

Comment: no that didn't work here, I received the same error as earlier; "The log cannot be rebuilt because there were open transactions/users when the database was shutdown, no checkpoint occurred to the database, or the database was read-only. This error could occur if the transaction log file was manually deleted or lost due to a hardware or environment failure."

Comment: This article may be helpful http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/creating-detaching-re-attaching-and-fixing-a-suspect-database/

Comment: thank you dbsoftware, I'm trying it ill let you know if it worked

Comment: Hi @user3120232, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.